# ¿Cómo invocar un parámetro de un procedimiento a otro procedimiento?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Tengo una duda:
¿Es posible heredar un parametro de un procedimiento a otro procedimiento?
Para que el procedimiento no tenga que volver a pedir el mismo parametro.

O abra otra forma de emplear ese parametro?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PK1 IS
  PROCEDURE obtener_nombre (p_id in number);
  PROCEDURE obtener_rol;  --- sin parametro de entrada
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PK1 IS
  PROCEDURE obtener_nombre (p_id in number)
  IS
    xnombre varchar2(250);
  
  BEGIN
    select nombre 
           into xnombre
   from empleados
   where id = p_id;
  END obtener_nombre;

  
 PROCEDURE obtener_rol
 IS

 xrol varchar2(250);
 BEGIN
  select rol into xrol 
  from empleados_org
  where id = p_id; ----- ¿Es posible heredar un parametro de un procedimiento a otro procedimiento?

 END;
 END obtener_id
END PK1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes compartir parámetros entre procedimientos, En ese sentido, PL/SQL es como cualquier otro lenguaje de programación y, ni en C, Pascal o C#, por mencionar algunos, podrías compartir un parámetro entre dos funciones o métodos distintos.

Dicho esto, si que existen mecanismos para almacenar y compartir el estado entre llamadas a distintos procedimientos de un mismo paquete y es que estos tienen soporte para definir variables globales (al paquete).

Estos vendrían siendo análogos a los atributos o miembros de un objeto o de un registro, en otros lenguajes.

Debes tener en cuenta que dichos datos son mantenidos durante la sesión, y no puedes compartir datos entre distintas sesiones.

Así, podrías declarar tu paquete de esta manera:

```
create or replace package PK1 is
  pkg_empleado_id number := null;
  procedure SetID(p_id in number);
  procedure obtener_nombre;
  procedure obtener_rol; 
end;
/

create or replace package body PK1 is

  procedure SetID(p_id in number) is
  begin
    pkg_empleado_id := p_id;
  end SetID;

  procedure obtener_nombre is
    xnombre varchar2(250);
  begin
    select nombre 
      into xnombre
      from empleados
     where id = pkg_empleado_id;
  end obtener_nombre;

  procedure obtener_rol is
    xrol varchar2(250);
  begin
    select rol into xrol 
      from empleados_org
     where id = pkg_empleado_id; 
  end obtener_rol;
end PK1;
/
```

Como puedes observar, ahora he declarado ambos procedimientos sin parámetro y he añadido el procedimiento `setID()`, que es el que establece el valor del `id` del empleado.

Debo aclarar que nada impide que almacenes el valor desde el procedimiento `obtener_nombre()`, pero yo en realidad prefiero que la intención de cada procedimiento sea clara y se explique por su nombre y por eso lo he hecho de esta manera.

Así le evito más de un dolor de cabeza a quién esté dándole mantenimiento a este código en 5 años. Incluso a mi mismo, pues fácilmente podría simplemente invertir el orden de las llamadas o quitar la llamada a `obtener_nombre()` sin advertir que todo se romperá al hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias por compartir conocimiento

Comment: ¿Si tengo que insertar en una tabla (columnas:= id, numero de control, descripción)pero el registro ya existe, es posible borrar el registro de la tabla(para evitar emplear update) y preservar el numero de control ?

Comment: Suena a una nueva pregunta, no veo que relación tiene con esta respuesta o su pregunta. En general, es posible preservarlo todo. En la práctica, no siempre conviene; sería de ver a detalle para poder dar una recomendación.

Comment: De axuerdo detallare en un pregunta

Comment: He añadido mi pregunta, cualquier sugerencia estaré pendiente

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/596467/c%c3%b3mo-preservar-la-informaci%c3%b3n-de-una-fila-si-el-registro-se-debe-borrar-cuando