# ¿Cómo preservar la información de una fila, si el registro se debe borrar cuando ya existe?

Tags: sql, plsql

Bueno pasa lo siguiente tengo una tabla llamada XXOM_CABECERA.

-Definición

```
CREATE TABLE "APEX_EBS_EXTENSION"."XXOM_CABECERA" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "CONTROL_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE), 
    "GENERATION_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE), 
    "DESCRIPCION" VARCHAR2(240 BYTE),
    "CREATE_BY" NUMBER, 
    "CREATION_DATE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, 
    "LAST_UPDATED_BY" NUMBER, 
    "LAST_UPDATE_DATE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, 
    "LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN" NUMBER
   );


    --------------------------------------------------------
    --  DDL for Index XXOM_CABECERA_U1
    --------------------------------------------------------
    
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "APEX_EBS_EXTENSION"."XXOM_CABECERA_U1" ON "APEX_EBS_EXTENSION"."XXOM_CABECERA" ("CONTROL_NUMBER","GENERATION_NUMBER","DESCRIPCION");
```

Si al ejecutar el procedimiento de insertar se encuentra que el registro ya existe entonces que borre el registro de la tabla y vuelva a insertar con los nuevos datos pero preservando :

- CONTROL_NUMBER
- GENERATION_NUMBER

¿Es posible guardarlo esos datos en variables sin necesidad de guardarlos en una tabla adicional?

Comment: ¿qué es que _un registro ya exista_? ¿Simplemente que ya exista un registro con el mismo ID? ¿Por qué no simplemente hacer un update sobre el registro?

Comment: Un registro existente es en el que ya existe control_number, generation_number y descripcion. Con respecto al realizar el update se me comento que para no generar mas sabanas de código se emplease en su lugar el borrado del registro. Ya que es una tabla con 170 columnas y tambien esta existe una tabla de detalle.

Comment: No me queda claro cómo identificar si un registro ya existe. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y agregar un select que nos indique si un registro ya existe o no?

Comment: Hola, supongo que para saber si existe buscas primero el registro usando el índice, si es así y existe ¿ porqué borrarlo y no hacer un UPDATE del resto de los campos?

Comment: Muchas gracias usare un update